# type of ajax calls for [HttpDelete] Asp.Net MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

What type of `ajax` calls will `[HttpDelete]` MVC attribute listens to? Say I have below `JsonResult` decorated with `[HttpDelete]` attribute.

```
[HttpDelete]
public JsonResult DeleteData(string id)
{
   //deleting the data
   return new Json{Data="Deleted", JsonRequestBehavior=JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet};
}
```

Now I've tried to invoke these `JsonResult` with `$.ajax` and `$.post` but both of them couldn't trace this controller method. Its obvious that I can get this done through `[HttpPost]` attribute decoration, but since I am deleting a `data` and this way it should be better IMHO. How would we go invoking Controller methods decorated with `[HttpDelete]` attribute through `ajax`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MVC will handle mapping the appropriate HTTP Verbs to their corresponding attributes, so that it knows which actions to target (i.e. `GET` maps to `[HttpGet]`, `POST` maps to `[HttpPost]`, etc.)

So if you have a Controller Action that is decorated with the `[HttpDelete]` attribute, you'll need to make a `DELETE` request to actually hit it.

This can be handled quite easily when making a jQuery AJAX call, as you'll just need to explicitly use `type: 'DELETE'` as seen below :

```
$.ajax({
    url: '{your-controller-action}',
    type: 'DELETE',
    success: function(result) {
          // Do something
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh right.. this is what I was missing.. We don't have any shorthands for this right? Like `$.post` and `$.get`...

Comment: I'm afraid not. Those that you posted (i.e. `$.post` and `$.get`) are the only [short-hand functions](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/shorthand-methods/) that map directly to a verb. So you'll just likely need to use `$.ajax` unless you want to create your own short-hand version for ease of use.

Comment: Oh.. Alright.. Thanks for the explanation champ.. :) Accepting in few moments.. :)

Comment: for this we need to pass parameter either way or there  is post or get to be used?